# Sitecore Powershell query for big images of a certain size

Tags: powershell-extensions

Can someone help me with the Sitecore Powershell query which  I can use for finding the images more than the given size.

Comment: In total pixel area? Larger than a certain width or height? In bytes? "large" is a relative term in more ways than one

Comment: @Prakash, is there an answer below that you can mark as accepted?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### August 2019 Update

There is a report included with SPE allowing you to find images by a specific size.

[image: Filter]

[image: Report]

#### January 2018 Update - 6 months later

So we've added a few more websites with media to our database. Updated results are below. I've also added a SQL Query example with looks promising but may give some people heartburn.

#### Example: Use Sitecore Query to find the content.

```
# Look for media greater than 500k in size.
Get-Item -Path "master:" -Query "/sitecore/media library/Images//*[@size > '500000']"
```

[image: Sitecore Query]

#### Query Performance

A quick non-scientific test produced the following timing

- `Get-ChildItem` followed by `Where-Object` returned **1764** items : 8.62 seconds
- `Get-Item` followed by `Axes` returned **1764** items : 2.08 seconds
- `Get-Item` using query returned **260** items (`Query.MaxItems` setting) : .6 seconds
- `Get-Item` using fast query returned **6240** items : 9.2 seconds
- `Sql Query` returned **1764** items : 5.1 seconds
- `Content Search API` returned **~3000** items (need to retest) : 2.1 seconds

#### Thoughts

I did not expect how fast the `Axes` command could be when searching recursively. I will have to try that out in more of the reports we have in SPE. Marek and Hishaam both gave some good examples at how you can achieve it. I hope that you will find the below queries useful when trying to determine an optimal query for your use case.

#### Performance Measurements

Run these queries in the ISE if you want to see an output of how long each command took to run. Substitute your own filters to see which meets your requirements.

```
Measure-Command {
    $items = Get-ChildItem -Path "/sitecore/media library" -Recurse | Where-Object { ($_.Size / 1) -gt 100000 }
} | Select-Object -Expand TotalSeconds

Measure-Command {
    # Call Initialize-Item so that SPE adds the automatic properties.
    $mediaItemContainer = Get-Item "master:/media library"
    $items = $mediaItemContainer.Axes.GetDescendants() | Where-Object { [int]$_.Fields["Size"].Value -gt 100000 } | Initialize-Item
} | Select-Object -Expand TotalSeconds

Measure-Command {
    $items = Get-Item -Path "master:" -Query "/sitecore/media library//*[@size > '100000']"
} | Select-Object -Expand TotalSeconds

Measure-Command {
    $items = Get-Item -Path "master:" -Query "fast:/sitecore/media library//*[@size > '100000']"
} | Select-Object -Expand TotalSeconds

Measure-Command {
    Import-Function -Name Invoke-SqlCommand
    $database = Get-Database -Name "master"
    $connection = [Sitecore.Configuration.Settings]::GetConnectionString($database.Name)
    $sizeFieldId = "{6954B7C7-2487-423F-8600-436CB3B6DC0E}"
    $parameters = @{
        "size" = 100000
        "fieldId" = $sizeFieldId
    }

    $query = "SELECT [ItemId] ,[Value] FROM [dbo].[SharedFields] WHERE FieldId = @fieldId AND [Value] > @size UNION ALL SELECT [ItemId] ,[Value] FROM [dbo].[VersionedFields] WHERE [FieldId] = '{5BE6C122-84C9-4661-A0C9-3718909C8DAD}' AND [Value] > @size"
    $itemIds = Invoke-SqlCommand -Connection $connection -Query $query -Parameters $parameters | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "ItemId"
    $items = $itemIds | ForEach-Object { Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID $_ }
} | Select-Object -Expand TotalSeconds
```

### Content Search API

After much trial and error, I found a way to use the Content Search API to query the items. In the following example, I had to change the field type from `Single-line text` to `Number` on the `File` data template. SOLR then interpreted the field as a `float`. If you want to use this approach consider creating a computed field instead so you can leave the `File` template alone.

```powershell
$code = @"
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;

using Sitecore.ContentSearch;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Utilities;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.SearchTypes;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities;

namespace Demo {
    public class ExtendedSearchResultItem : Sitecore.ContentSearch.SearchTypes.SearchResultItem {
        [IndexField("size")]
        public float Size { get; set; }
    }

    public class SearchRunner {
        public IEnumerable<ExtendedSearchResultItem> DoSearch() {
            using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_master_index").CreateSearchContext())
            {
                var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<ExtendedSearchResultItem>();
                predicate = predicate.Or(i=> i.Size > 100);
                return context.GetQueryable<ExtendedSearchResultItem>().Where(predicate).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -ReferencedAssemblies @("Sitecore.Kernel", "Sitecore.ContentSearch", "Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq")

$search = New-Object Demo.SearchRunner
Measure-Command {
    $items = $search.DoSearch()
} | Select-Object -Expand TotalSeconds
```

Comment: `Get-Item` using query returned only 260 because that's the default value of `Query.MaxItems` in config (it used to be 100 pre-SC 8.1). `fast` probably returned that number due to also counting language versions.

Comment: Just wanted mention the fact that caching is heavily affecting the numbers in the performance piece above. From my understanding the first `Get-ChildItem` is seeding the cache for all the subsequent calls (other than `fast:` which I don't believe is ever cached).  If order and caching (only running this on very rare occasions) is irrelevant and you have a very large result, I almost always default to `fast:`

Answer (score 8):

This should do the trick

```
# Call Initialize-Item so that SPE adds the automatic properties.
$mediaItemContainer = Get-Item "master:/media library"
$items = $mediaItemContainer.Axes.GetDescendants() | Where-Object { [int]$_.Fields["Size"].Value -gt 100000 } | Initialize-Item
```

And if you want to see a nice report use:

```
# Call Initialize-Item so that SPE adds the automatic properties.
$mediaItemContainer = Get-Item "master:/media library"
$items = $mediaItemContainer.Axes.GetDescendants() | Where-Object { [int]$_.Fields["Size"].Value -gt 100000 } | Initialize-Item

if ($items.Count -eq 0){
    Show-Alert "There are no big media items"
} else {
    $props = @{
    InfoTitle = "Big media items"
    InfoDescription = "Lists all media items which are bigger than 100000 bytes."
    PageSize = 25}
}

$items |
    Show-ListView @props -Property @{Label="Name"; Expression={$_.DisplayName} },
        @{Label="Updated"; Expression={$_.__Updated} },
        @{Label="Updated by"; Expression={$_."__Updated by"} },
        @{Label="Size"; Expression={$_.Size} },
        @{Label="Path"; Expression={$_.ItemPath} }
```

Answer (score 4):

Please find below the script you may use to get the images which their size is greater than a defined value.

```
## Change the path your your specific container and also the language
$mediaItemContainer = Get-Item "master:/media library" -Language en-GB

$media = $mediaItemContainer.Axes.GetDescendants()

ForEach($mediaItem in $media){

    $size = [int]$mediaItem.Fields["Size"].Value

    ## Change the value 20 to your required size
    if($size -gt 20){
        $mediaItem.Name
    }
}
```

Note that the value "20" is in Byte.