# Get all items where a certain template appears in its template inheritance

Tags: templates, sitecore-query

Is there a way to get all items where a certain template appears in its template inheritance?

Say I want to get all items where `/sitecore/Templates/Common/Sections/Search` appears in that inheritance tree.

Ultimately, what I want to do is get all items in Sitecore that contain a certain field. I tried achieving this with a Sitecore query (`/sitecore/templates//*[contains(@__Base template,'{C8615DF9-65D1-4529-859F-9ABB4DA977B8}')]`), however, this only returns items that directly inherit from the specified template.

This doesn't give me complete coverage so it seems that I would need something that works recursively...

Comment: Did one of these answers help solve your issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Sitecore PowerShell Extensions

At first your question made me think of [this](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6803/sitecore-powershell-query-for-big-images-of-a-certain-size/6811#6811) where the user wants to find media items of a certain length. I encourage you to check that out to see some different ways you can use SPE to query items.

#### Option 1

Your case is similar but may be a little expensive. In that case the Sitecore Content Search API may be ideal for you.

You'll need a computed field that stores all the base templates in the index. It's very likely the field is simply not being indexed by default and you need to uncomment it as described [here](https://mikerobbins.co.uk/2013/12/17/sitecore-7-search-by-base-templates/). Alternatively, you can add a computed index as seen [here](https://mikael.com/2013/05/sitecore-7-query-items-that-inherits-a-template/).

```powershell
# Taking a guess at the field name in the search index.
$criteria = @(
    @{Filter="Contains";Field="_templates";Value="c8615df965d14529859f9abb4da977b8"}
)
Find-Item -Index sitecore_master_index -Criteria $criteria
```

#### Option 2

Matthew makes a good point in the comment below. Another option would be to query all of the items under the specified root and test for the inheritance.

```powershell
$templateId = [Sitecore.Data.ID]::Parse("{76036F5E-CBCE-46D1-AF0A-4143F9B557AA}")
$searchPath = "master:/sitecore/content/home"
$allthethings = @(Get-Item -Path $searchPath) + @(Get-ChildItem -Path $searchPath -Recurse)
foreach($onething in $allthethings) {
    $doesItInherit = [Sitecore.Data.Managers.TemplateManager]::GetTemplate($onething.TemplateID, $onething.Database).InheritsFrom($templateId)
    if($doesItInherit) {
        $onething
    }
}
```

#### Option 3 :thumbs-up:

Likely the best option is to simply use the Link Database to find all items referenced.

```powershell
# Sample Item
$template = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{76036F5E-CBCE-46D1-AF0A-4143F9B557AA}"
Get-ItemReferrer -Item $template | Where-Object { $_.Paths.IsContentItem }
```

A more complete example for looking at all levels of inheritance can be found [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/15168/95).

Comment: It briefly mentions it in the linked post, but I think it's worth calling out that this would impact index building time and the size of the index for large content trees, particularly since it would apply to the entire content tree. If this isn't an ongoing need, it should probably be disabled again once the search task is completed.

Answer (score 2):

#### Not using Sitecore Query

Not using Sitecore Query. The reason is - as you also point out yourself - Sitecore simply does not have a by-query way of recursively deducing the complete template inheritance chain.

### The SQL route

But you *can* rather easily get the Item IDs you want. Your question doesn't mention what the actual purpose is of what you're trying to do here, so I can only point in a direction, hoping you can take it from there.

Sitecore stores all *field values* in one of three tables in SQL. `[SharedFields]`, `[UnversionedFields]` and `[VersionedFields]`. Which one your field belongs to, depends on the settings defined for the field. Like if it is marked `Shared`, it will be in `[SharedFields]` and so on.

Knowing this, it becomes rather simple. The `[UnversionedFields]` table looks like this:

[image]

And so querying it for what you want, would be as simple as:

```
SELECT [ItemId]
  FROM [sc80rev140922_master].[dbo].[UnversionedFields]
  WHERE FieldId='B5E02AD9-D56F-4C41-A065-A133DB87BDEB'
```

(replace database name and FieldId value to fit your own, obviously)

### The caveat

The above will not find any Items, where the field in question has never had a value (is NULL). This may invalidate this solution for your use case, your question isn't 100% clear on that.

Comment: Thanks for the very quick reply! Unfortunately, the caveat there would invalidate that possible solution. It seems that the best route at the moment is to write out an algorithm that recursively gets all templates that inherit from my Base Page template. Once I have those, I can iterate through them and grab all items that are created from those templates. It seems that this would give me coverage of all the items I need... in theory of course.

Comment: Give it a while. I'm pretty sure there's also a way to achieve this using SPE, and we have quite many SPE enthusiasts on the site ;-).  I don't have the skills myself to help you with this one however.

Comment: Yes, using Sitecore query you may not get items using inherited template. To have work around, to get items having inherited templates i.e inherited fields. you should check field name/Id to get all items based if you are using the fast query, you can use like this Ex: fast:/sitecore/content/Website/Home//*[@MyField!='']