# Get Items by template id in a scheduled task

Tags: sitecore-api, scheduled-tasks

Scenario:

I have over 10,000 items in my `sitecore/content` tree. Nearly 2,000 of them are thrived from the `Article` template. Inside of the `Article` items, there are two important fields: `Is Featured - Checkbox`, and `Featured Expiration Date - Date`.

I like to create a scheduled task that finds **only** the items that thrive from `**@@[templateId="{My template id}"]`, and `Fields["Is Featured"].value == "1"`. After that, I would check for the value of `Fields["Featured Expiration Date"]`. If the value is `<= DateTime.Now`; then, I'm going to remove the `Is Featured` flag, and update the item.

Is this even possible as a scheduled task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The scheduled task is going to be a tool used to execute code you've written. There are ways to [create custom commands](https://www.degdigital.com/insights/how-to-create-sitecore-scheduled-task/) in C# or use the existing on that is included with Sitecore PowerShell Extensions (SPE).

For simplicity, I'll show you how to do that in SPE. Here's a really good [section](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/tasks.html) in the book covering the creating of task scripts.

### Examples

In this [question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6803/sitecore-powershell-query-for-big-images-of-a-certain-size/6811#6811) I showed a few ways to perform queries in SPE. In the following I'll use the Sitecore Query syntax.

**Example:** The following queries all items that have the *IsFeatured* field checked true.

```powershell
Get-Item -Path "master:" -Query "/sitecore/content//*[@IsFeatured = '1']"
```

**Example:** The following queries all the items with a *NewsDate* greater than 2017-10-01.

```powershell
Get-Item -Path "master:" -Query "/sitecore/content//*[@NewsDate > '20171001T000000']"
```

To combine the queries together you can do

`[@IsFeatured = '1' and @NewsDate > '20161001T000000']`.

Here's a nice screenshot of me running the command inside of the Console bundled with SPE.

[image: Console Example]

After the PowerShell script is written and saved. You can configured the scheduled task.

[image: Wizard]

[image: Task Wizard]

[image: Schedule]

[image: PowerShellScriptCommand]

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to install `SPE` module like @Michael West suggested, there is another way to do this. You can implement a custom class for your agent and add it to schedule with a config patch.

A config patch to add your class to the schedule can look like this:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <scheduling>
      <agent type="YourNamespace.YourAgentClass, YourAssemblyName" method="Run" name="AgentName" interval="01:00:00"/>
    </scheduling>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

In that config patch, you specify your agent's class name, a method to execute (`Run`) and interval.

Your custom class can look like this:

```
public class YourAgentClass
{
    public void Run()
    {

    }
}
```

Inside `Run` method you can use search index to find your items:

```
using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext())
{
    var results = context.GetQueryable<ArticleSearchResultItem>()
              .Where(item => item.TemplateId == ArticleTemplateId
                             && item.IsFeatured == true)
              .ToList();
}
```

`ArticleSearchResultItem` class can look like this:

```
public class ArticleSearchResultItem
{
    [IndexField("_group")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(IndexFieldIDValueConverter))]
    public virtual ID ItemID { get; set; }

    [IndexField("_template")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(IndexFieldIDValueConverter))]
    public virtual ID TemplateId { get; set; }

    [IndexField("isfeatured")]
    public virtual bool IsFeatured{ get; set; }
}
```

You can also extend existing `SearchResultItem` class.