# Broken Links Report Options Powershell vs. Fast Query?

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am currently trying to find and delete broken links in the Sitecore master database. I am using a version of [this script](https://gitlab.com/viet.hoang/workshop/blob/master/Sitecore%20PowerShell%20Scripts/Broken%20Internal%20Links%20Report%20With%20Additional%20Info.ps1). The problem I am having is that the number of items in the content tree is huge (thousands of items) so the site becomes unresponsive whenever I run the script to search the whole database.

The script I am using is currently using `Get-ChildItem` as seen below, in order to get the items to search for broken links:

`$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $root.ProviderPath -Recurse | HasBrokenLink -IncludeAllVersions (!$searchVersion)`

I am wondering if there is a faster method I can use to search the content tree, such as fast query. I have looked everywhere, but haven't found any examples of a broken link report script that uses anything other than `Get-ChildItem` and `-Recurse`.

Is there a better method to find broken links in the master database?

Answer (score 4):

You can have a look at the following [answer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/6811/95) for several ways to query items in PowerShell.

I would suggest you try the call to Axes to get items fast.

```powershell
$mediaItemContainer = Get-Item "master:/media library" 
$items = $mediaItemContainer.Axes.GetDescendants() | 
    Where-Object { [int]$_.Fields["Size"].Value -gt 100000 } | Initialize-Item
```

Looks like I already changed this behavior for a future release (maybe 4.8).

```powershell
$items = @($root) + @(($root.Axes.GetDescendants() | Initialize-Item)) | 
    HasBrokenLink -IncludeAllVersions (!$searchVersion)
```